# I want to grep/gsub empty, space and a hyphen and replace that with NA in R

Tags: r

I have the following data,

```
a <- c('a','1','',' ','-')
```

I want to use grep to search '',' ','-' in the above vector, what is the pattern I should use to search, i want to use the same pattern in gsub.Also please explain the nitty-gritties of the pattern you are suggesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this to determine and replace your query

```
gsub("-|\\s+|^$",NA,a)
```

**Logic**:

`gsub` will replace the pattern with NA, the pattern states that if "a" as input contains any dash (-), or multiple occurrence of one or more than spaces(\s+) or any missing character (^$) should be replaced .

- `\\s` means space in regex,
- `+` means 1 or more character,
- `^`  means start,
- `$` means end of a string,
- a pipe symbol is OR (`|`)in regex.

so, `\\s+` means one or more spaces here, `^$` together means the start and end is together which suggests there is nothiing between them, a dash can be taken as it is. All these special meaning here are combined using pipe( `|` ) , the **OR** operator.

---

You can extensively look into the detailed meaning by typing `help(regex)` or `?regex` in your R terminal

**Output:**

```
#> gsub("-|\\s+|^$",NA,a)
#[1] "a" "1" NA  NA  NA
```

Comment: why do we need a '+' ,even without a '+' it works.Can you clarify ?

Comment: It's interesting to note that `gsub` does not convert the `NA` to the two character string`"NA"` but rather to the `NA_character_`  needed here.